# 3D array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need a 3D array like a runes['red'][0]['test']

How I can do it?

```
    var runes = {}

runes['red'] = [
    'test': ['loh']
]
runes['blue'] = {}
runes['yellow'] = {}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want an object containing an array with objects inside it? That would look like this:

```
runes["red"] = [
    {test: "loh"},
    {anotherTest: "anotherLoh"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var runes = {};        // Object

runes.red = [          // containing Array of Objects
  {'test': 'loh'},     // 0  
  {'test': 'blah'},    // 1
  {property1: "value", property2: "value"}  // 2...
];

alert( runes.red[0].test ); // loh
```